# Can I re-enter the Cloister of Trials after completing them?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I've just finished the Kilika temple, and along the way, entered the last room with the fayth.  Once I was there, I couldn't go back and try to find the hidden room.  After getting Ifrit and leaving the temple, I tried to re-enter it, but the door wouldn't open.

Is there any way to get back in there and grab the stuff I missed the first time around?

Comment: NOTE: It depends on the version -- in some versions, attempting to revisit the cloisters will trigger the Dark Fayth encounter: Dark Valefor, Dark Shiva, Dark Ifrit, etc. Each of them is *significantly* more dangerous than pretty much any non-optional encounter, and most of them will wipe an unprepared party in a single round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it will take you a while to reach the point in which you are free to do so. Once you have the airship, you have to finish an event at Highbridge.

> Talk to Maester Mika.

The exception to this rule is the Bevelle Temple cloister of trials. If memory serves, that's a one-off, and you won't be able to redo it once you've finished.

Also, for players of the HD Remaster, or International/PAL versions, it's worth mentioning the entrance to Besaid will be blocked by a Warrior Monk and his Dark Aeon by this point. You won't be able to enter Besaid until they are defeated.

Comment: This goes for the one is Besaid also right (like I can re-enter)? I too was a little quick on this because I mostly wanted to play blitzball asap.

Comment: @Dupree3 You can reenter Besaid. The only problem is, if you're playing the HD Remaster, you have to go through a very difficult boss fight first.

Comment: Thanks that's all I needed to know! I'm not much concerned about bosses so long as I can get back in. Bosses are beatable, inaccessible doors are not haha

Comment: you'll be concerned after you understand how strong are the dark aeons :P You kinda _require_ max stats

Answer (score 2):

actually you can reenter Kilika cloister of trials much sooner, namely once you finnish the events at Djose temple (after acquiring Ixion)

It is the Fayth Chamber at the end of the trials with the extra items inside that you can only access after the highbridge scene (the one Yuna always goes into alone to pray for a new Aeon at each temple) this is the case for all the temples fayth chambers

on a side note about revisiting the trials for the destruction spheres :

- you cannot backtrack early to Besaid trials like you do at Kilika since Isaaru the summoner is using it up until until after Dark Valefor appears after the highbridge scene, meaning you cant get Anima before killing Dark Valefor if you missed it during your first visit
- you can reenter Djose temple as early as upon reaching the thunderplains
- Macalania temple can be revisited after you leave bevelle and get dropped off in the woods by the airship (just before the calm lands) but Dark Shiva will already be blocking the way
- you cannot ever reenter bevelle temple but you also cannot miss its destruction sphere, thank god cause that mini-game is lame, ill note the extra chest with the spear for Kimahri in the bevelle trials has nothing to do with the destruction sphere

also its the opening of the chest itself that triggers the Anima Locks, the item inside has nothing to do with it

just to reiterate it is only the fayth chambers that are opened by the highbridge scene, dark Aeons appear at different times and each temples cloisters are reopened at different times too

two years late reply but i hope this helps someone as ive found there is alot of confusion and wrong information out there

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you can re-enter Kilika CoT after completing the Djose CoT? IIRC, you can't even revisit Kilika until you obtain the airship.

Comment: After completing Operation Mi'ihen and finnishing the events at Djose Temple the Roads back through mushroom rock and Mi'ihen highroad are re-opened taking you back to Luca if you wish to walk back, and the S.S Liki and Wino ships are now also useable taking you to Kilika and Besaid. You can do this at any point up untill entering Macalania Temple since then you go to war with Yevon and you cannot go backwards because Guadosalam is blocked. (only untill you get the airship then you can reenter Guadosalam)

Comment: Interesting, I did some research myself and other sources seem to validate that. It's been a while since I played, and I never knew you could that.

Comment: yea its best to wait until after you kill the Spherimorph boss at the Lake in Macalania Woods (triggers Jhect spheres) then do a massive walk back to besaid to grab the sphere there before Dark Valefor (you can actually collect 9/10 spheres at this point)and do the 2nd butteryfly hunts and get the ace wizard on the s.s wino and the chest with 4 softs at mushroom rock. handy for playing blitz early too since you can recruit 47 of the 60 available players just between Besaid and the Thunderplains (unfortunately not Brother, Wakka or Nimrook) or just get it all later it doesnt really matter haha